# Why python create a module whose name is `__main__` at first

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import

After reading some docs, I understand how python imports a module, and what will happen if I import a module. But all of these seems not help.

When I debug a python file with `python3` in `virtualenv(vscode)`, python seems to create a new module whose name is `__main__`
 I did some google search but failed, I can find any thing useful

Note that without `vitualenv` or use `python2` in `virtualenv` to debug in `vscode` will work perfect.

Here are some pictures about the problem I'm facing.
Sorry I can't add any image now, so I put some link below, hope these won't affect a lot

1. [Now my pythonPath is `VirtualEnvs/test/bin/python` python3 in virtualenv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2qq7.gif)
2. [Now my pythonPath is `/usr/local/bin/python3` not in any virtualenv!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3APgv.gif)

My questions are:
1. why does python creates this empty module?
2. how can I fix this problem in `vscode`?

Comment: `__main__` is not a new module, it's the name of the current file Python is executing. The name is stored in `__name__`.

Comment: There are also a few situations where a `__main__.py` is part of the game. The asker should give more context.

Comment: You probably wanna read [What is if __name__ == "__main__" in Python?](https://tutswiki.com/if-name-main-in-python/)

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, but this cannot help me solve my problem @ChankeyPathak

Comment: I upload some gif, may be you can understand what I was talking about. @ChristianDean